# Console.ReadLine returns empty string for unicode input when input/output encoding is Encoding.UTF8?

Tags: c#, unicode, .net-core

Targeting `netcoreapp2.1` with this code:

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.InputEncoding = Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    while (true)
    {
        var line = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"Length: {line.Length}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Bytes: {string.Join(", ", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line).Select(b => b.ToString()))}");
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

When I type <kbd>что</kbd> (a Russian word), then the output is:

```
Length: 3
Bytes: 0, 0, 0
<<there is an empty line here>>
```

When I type <kbd>Hello world</kbd>, then the output is:

```
Length: 11
Bytes: 72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100
Hello world
```

If I set the input/output encoding to `Encoding.Unicode` then it works as expected (the Russian word yields six bytes like you'd expect). What gives?

Comment: Internally, strings are reprented in Unicode (UTF16-LE). And in a .Net Core Console application, the base Encoding support is extremely limited (you need a NuGet package to expand it). The same goes for the Font support. Stick to Unicode for the Console. UTF-8 to write to a file.

Comment: I would expect `OutputEncoding` to impact `Console.WriteLine`, but not `Console.ReadLine`... have you tried tweaking `Console.InputEncoding`?

Comment: @MarcGravell You may have missed the first line of my `Main` method in the code above; or perhaps I could have been more explicit that "If I set the input/output encoding" means changing that line

Comment: Same for the Chinese characters here, once you've input Chinese text via keyboard you need to let console to set input encoding to Unicode otherwise another non-UTF(a semi-GB2132) stream is being set to your variable.